# Can firstOrCreate be treated atomically in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an API that another application hooks into to upload some user data. Each peice of data belongs to a user and the user's email address is included in each API request. If the email doesn't exist in the users table then a new user is created, otherwise the new data will be added under the existing user.

I need to if `firstOrCreate` will be guaranteed to return a `User` object if two API request are made back to back. In my current code, I am querying the database and if it user doesn't exist I create one. But I am having an issue where if two API calls are made back to back, I get two inserts into the database (two users with the same email). I have since added a unique constraint on the email column but I want to be sure that if I use `firstOrCreate` I will be able to proceed after that knowing that I either have the existing user or I have successfully created on.

Comment: Wrap it in a transaction? https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#database-transactions

Comment: this article could be helpful: http://fideloper.com/laravel-database-transactions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel [`firstOrCreate`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/tree/master/Eloquent/Builder.php#L253-L266) does not have atomic guards. But, since you have a `UNIQUE` constraint on the column, the database will enforce atomicity for you. Thus:

```
$params = [ 'email' => 'foo@example.com', /* ... */ ];
try {
    $user = User::firstOrCreate($params);
} catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex) {
    $user = User::firstOrCreate($params);
}
```

If this fails the first time, then you've got contention. So it retries the attempt. Presumably, the second attempt will return the first record matching. However, be warned that the `Illuminate\Database\QueryException` may occur for a multitude of reasons, unique key violations being one of them. Thus the second attempt may be made but still not actually return a user.

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I was looking for. Although can the second firstOrCreate not just be first? If we got a QueryException because of a duplicate key, we should not try to create it again since at that point it would already be there.

Answer (score 0):

I think that unique constraint should suffice:

> The UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints both provide a guarantee for uniqueness for a column or set of columns.

[source on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Add unique key to the email column.
`$table->string('email')->unique();`

Comment: It's not my firstOrCreate function, it is part of the framework: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent

Comment: Ya. It will create the record if not exist. Just add the `unique key` will fix your problem.